# Material expansion panel scrolling problem on opening when in multiple tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-expansion-panel

I have 2 material accordions in separate tabs. When im going into 2nd tab, which has first expansion panel expanded by default, and trying to open last expansion panel (ACC 8 in my stackblitz example) it doesnt scroll into its content and its getting out of view.

I tried to solve it with scrollIntoView method in afterExpand and opened events but in best case it returns to correct position after scrolling to bottom. Is there a way to do this correctly?

Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7jhsn

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in my browser (Chrome), the expansion panel opens as expected

Comment: @JSONDerulo you need to go straight to second tab, leave first panel opened, then position scroll in a way that panel "ACC 8' will be in the midde or upper part of screen, after that expand it, you will see that 'CONTENT 8' will be off-screen.